# Nothing appears to happen when pressing Enter in the middle of a line

Tags: bug, stacks-editor, newline

When using the beta Stacks Editor<sup>1</sup> in this [example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385613/178179), pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> doesn't create a new line right before character `W` in the rich text editor mode. Nothing appears to happen *in the editor*.

Env: Chrome version 108.0.5359.125 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10. The issue is not present on Android 12 + Chrome or Android 12 + Opera.

Demo:

[image]

---

1. You have to enable using the "new" beta editor in [your account's preferences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current). When you do, it's used when editing *answers* (not questions) on Meta Stack Exchange and Meta Stack Overflow. The "new" editor is also the only available editor for creating new questions on Stack Overflow using the new question wizard. It's also the only available editor on Teams.

Comment: Side note:  does anyone know a good [screen recording app showing which keys are pressed for Microsoft Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/78441/903)? A video would make it easier to understand.

Comment: You could ask about it on _Software Recommendations_ sister site of SE.

Comment: There is [a very nice Blender.SE Meta thread](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) about recording your screen and uploading the result.

Answer (score 1):

This is the example:

Hello.
World.